# If A is greater than B by Value then do something

Tags: php

I have two variables with numerical values. I want to execute an `if` statement something like this:

```
$A = '8111'; 
$B = '8000'; 
$difference  = '50';
```

If `$A` is greater than `$B` by `$difference` then do something.

Comment: Check out [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php). It's a very instructive PHP course which you will learn all basics, like the one you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've practically written the code in your comments!

```
if (abs((int)$A - (int)$B) >= (int)$difference) { 
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Yes this! I have been searching all over for it.

Comment: Assuming `$A` is bigger than `$B` - otherwise you may want to check the `max()` from `$A` or `$B` minus `$difference` is >= the other or something?

Comment: you should use abs($A-$B) instead, for when $A is smaller than $B

Comment: @FranzGleichmann probably so, feel free to edit and improve the answer.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Sorry, it got rejected, I've added your change.